# On the "Help Center > The Stack Exchange Model"

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center

From the Help Center, *[Help Center > The Stack Exchange Model](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/more-help)*:

> ... If you are experience issues not documented on the site ...

Is this proper? If not, what should it be?

Comment: OK, slightly rhetorical, but keeping to form.

Comment: Fixed. From MY PHONE! Gotta love the new system.